# How to do image stitching using opencv (python), simplecv or pil?

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, simplecv

How to do image stitching using opencv (python), [simplecv](http://www.simplecv.org) or pil? or any other python library, i have an image which looks like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2169082/puzzle.png), created from 200 images, i need to stitch them in the correct order to form an image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9035758/176769

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[opencv]+stitching

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6017943/176769

Comment: @karlphillip - I think this is more of a jigsaw puzzle problem than precise alignment. Thanks for the first link to the ImageJ plugin - very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the order they are in?

Frankly if you are hoping to do it with image recognition and you only need one off I would use mechanical turk and let somebody spend 15mins doing it for a $1

edit: the images are very small which makes it tricky to find enough features to match. I would start with a histogram approach to group images with similar sets of colours. Then you could use a fourier transform to find lines/structure at a similar direction and spacing.  Are the image allowed to be rotated?

Comment: then how to do it with numpy? i suggested these library coz they could detect RBG? and yes i can pay 5$ for that but where to find that person lol!